# Jquery Ajax Json object not showing after Jquery update to 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

im having a problem with a project im working on.. the programmer before me used jquery 1.4.4 and now ive updated it to 1.10.2 cause of designer using bootstrap..

but when i run it in 1.10.2 one of the objects that worked in 1.4.4 is not showing in 1.10.2

this is the script that isnt showing up in 1.10.2
    
    var interests = new Array();

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitInterestPreferencesDialogs();

    $(".Interest").live('click', function () {
        $(".SelectedInterest").removeClass("SelectedInterest");

        AddInterest(this.id);
    });

  jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "/Bubble/MyInterests",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#interestContainer").empty();
            $("#interestTemplate").render(data).appendTo("#interestContainer");
            RefreshPage();
        }

    });
});

 <div id="interestouter">        
    <div id="interestContainer"></div>
</div>

<script id="interestTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="{{= Id}}" icon="{{= Icon}}" class="{{= CssClass}}">
        <div class="interesticon {{= Icon}}" title="{{= Name}}">
        </div>
        {{= Name}}
    </div>
</script>
```

can anyone see where my problem is.. the only thing that has changed is im using jquery version 1.10.2 insted of 1.4.4

Comment: you have some extra `$.` typo?

Comment: btw i don't see any data that you're sending in ajax, maybe you're just pulling the content?

Comment: thats kinda my problem to.. as i wrote.. i didnt write the code.. but i needed to update the jquery to be able to use bootstrap.. and after update it just wont show

Comment: what it does is its suppose to show a top menu bar with some stuff thats generic.. atleast from what i understand.. so im thinking the there should also be some kinda refference to this is in the master view but i cant find that eiter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery docs:

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

So this

```
$(".Interest").live('click', function () {
    $(".SelectedInterest").removeClass("SelectedInterest");

    AddInterest(this.id);
});
```

should be replaced with this

```
$(".Interest").on('click', function () {
    $(".SelectedInterest").removeClass("SelectedInterest");

    AddInterest(this.id);
});
```

Comment: the $, isnt suppose to be there.. thats a type.. the thing is.. its working when i use jquery 1.4.4  but when changing it to 1.10.2 it just stops working

Comment: I just rewrote my answer, .live() is deprecated.  Use .on() instead.